# PanoramaGL how to stop rotating

Tags: ios, image, 360-degrees

I am using PanoramaGL to make a 360 degree rotating image,the problem is how can i make it stop rotating automatically?

Answer (score 2):

While researching for a solution on this case I've managed to get it working.

All you need to do on iOS is insert a line on PLViewBase.m, at method drawViewInternally.

After:

```
[camera rotateWithStartPoint:startPoint endPoint:endPoint];
```

Insert:

```
startPoint = endPoint;
```

This will trick PanoramaGL to assume the "first touch location" as the last one, therefore the "distance" between the drag points are always tiny enough to make a consistent and smooth scroll.

Then you just need to adjust the sensitivity. 10.0f did fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
plView.isScrollingEnabled = NO
```

Comment: The question is to not disable scrolling at all, but how to stop auto scrolling when user drags to one way. I really need to know too